# magento quantity shows negative value

Tags: magento

We are selling products through amazon and using M2Epro extension for this. We have orders from our site and amazon. Few products quantity shows as -1 in Magento admin side. What will be the reason for this. As I understand Magento will not display product if qty is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check configuration like below :

```
(System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Backorders >> Allow QTY below 0
```

Set to `No BackOreder`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But the value already 'No backorder'.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen constellations where qty is negative / < zero in a very small amount of client systems that we did not create from the scratch. The problem is, that the products with negative qty are "in stock/available" and can be bought by shop customers.

Instead of hunting down the reason i simply put a trigger:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER negative_stock_to_zero BEFORE UPDATE ON cataloginventory_stock_item 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.qty < 0 THEN
       NEW.qty = 0;
    END IF;
END;//
delimiter;
```

Of course you could also check if backordering is enabled/disabled in the IF-Clause - but thats up to you.